# PHP operator speed

Tags: php, operators

I've got two quick questions which I can't find on Google.

What's the correct name for this operator?

```
$a = ($b > 5) ? 'High' : 'Low';
```

And secondly, is there ever a situation when it's preferable over any other operator? I know 'if else' is a faster method and is easier to read and edit.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about faster, but at least that is objective. Easier to read and edit obviously are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a).

This [person](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/48/the-php-ternary-operator-fast-or-not) did some benchmarks, and the answer is that it depends on the situation.

Quoting from this doc:

```
// snippet 1
$tmp = isset($context['test']) ? $context['test'] : '';

// snippet 2
if (isset($context['test'])) {
    $tmp = $context['test'];
} else {
    $tmp = '';
}
```

> The right answer is: it depends. Most of the time, they are about the same speed and you don't need to care. But if $context['test'] contains a large amount of data, snippet 2 is much faster than snippet 1.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to trust the blog you posted; my own performance benchmarks don't put the counts anywhere near what he says, and his comments about PHP's copying method are outdated at best. [*Here is the performance running on 5.2.5*](http://codepad.org/EToVfPH7), and I got even more equal performance on 5.3.13.

Answer (score 0):

It's called ternary operator.

It's used for making your code simpler, and it sometimes helps you to combine two statements into just one.

Here goes an example. Instead of:

```
if($Disabled) $String = 'disabled'; else $String = '';
echo '<input type="text" ' . $String . '>';
```

You can use:

```
echo '<input type="text" ' . $Disabled ? 'disabled' : '' . '>';
```

I didn't simplify the code above on purpose, to clearly show my point. This way you have just one statement, avoiding the extra if / else. In some situations, it may help you. In others, you will see no benefit.

Comment: Only one assignment will be executed for the first snippet as well

Comment: I have updated the example to show my point more clearly. Thanks for pointing this out.